# Why isn’t “disharmony” spelled “*dysharmony”?

Tags: etymology, prefixes, latin, greek

*Disharmony* is a Greek word with a Latin prefix meaning “absence of harmony” or “bad harmony”. So why not spell it *dysharmony*, as one spells *dysfunction* or *dyspepsia*?

Comment: If you are looking for logic in word spellings, English is not the language for you.

Comment: Additionally, since this is an English language forum, the question should have been written in this way: "Why is 'disharmony' not spelled 'dysharmony?'" ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[*Dis-* is a Latin prefix](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dis-), whereas [*dys-* is a Greek one](http://thespellingblog.blogspot.com/2009/08/confusing-prefixes-dis-and-dys.html). Much of English stems from Latin, so it certainly makes sense for *dis-* to be the more common prefix, though you are correct that *dys-* as a prefix has a meaning similar to *dis-*.

*Dys-* is often used in a scientific context (where Greek gets a fair amount of use in addition to Latin) for terms like *dysgraphia* and *dyslexia*. *Dys-* tends to be used more to mean “bad, improper” rather than “the opposite of”, as you'll note from my examples; *dysgraphia* is not the opposite of writing, but rather means that one’s writing is impaired.

Comment: i found actually a word combination 'marital dysharmony' so this variant is also of some use

Comment: In medical terminology, **dys-** generally means "difficult", not "bad or improper" - *dyspnea*, difficulty breathing; *dysphagia*, difficulty eating; *dyslexia*, difficulty reading.  I do admit that *dysfunction*, as in "sexual dysfunction", could be read either way.